# How to get rid of the extra messages that show up in terminal window of VS Code while running java file?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Recently I have installed VS code and downloaded the coding pack for JAVA. But when I ran a hello world printing code I saw lots of other information that where displayed in the terminal window. How do I prevent this  from happening. The image below explains my problems :
[image]

I want to get rid of these messages and print hello world only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're no such settings for disabling execution scripts in **Terminal**, but we have some workaround.

1.Create `launch.json` and set `"console": "internalConsole",`. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in **Debug Console** and no execution scripts:

[image]

2.In `launch.json`, set `"console": "externalTerminal",`. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in external Terminal and no execution scripts:

[image]