# I tried running java on vscode. When I compile the file, the terminal renders it but it shows the full path (Attached a picture)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ac1p.jpg)

So how do I change it to my preference so that it doesn't show me the whole path instead a tiny bit maybe? Because the path is being shown every time and it is sometimes bigger in length than the output.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: [How to get rid of the extra messages that show up in terminal window of VS Code while running java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664289/how-to-get-rid-of-the-extra-messages-that-show-up-in-terminal-window-of-vs-code/67668025#67668025)

Answer (score 1):

There're no settings to meet your needs, but we can add `"debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing": true,` in **Settings.json** to clear the terminal before starting a new debug session in an integrated or external terminal.

Then every time you **Debug** or **Run without Debugging**, it will only show a list of execution scripts instead of many lists.